# Where can I get the full key list in jaxws properties map?

Tags: xml, cxf, jax-ws

I have a jaxws:client configuration like below. Would like to know where can I get the full list of key I can pass into the jaxws:properties map?

Example:
schema-validation-enabled
mtom-enabled
set-jaxb-validation-event-handler
....

```
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"

<jaxws:client>
 <jaxws:properties>
  <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false"></entry>
  <entry key="mtom-enabled" value="false" />
  <entry key="set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" value="false"></entry>
 </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

Comment: ever found an answer?